# PCAPNG : Relation b/w frame length (bytes) and Data length ( bytes)?

Tags: udp, wireshark, ethernet, pcap-ng

I have some PCAPNG file, one UDP packet has Frame length **187 Bytes (1496 bits)** and **Data length 472 Bytes**. All other packets fame length is greater than data length.

Please correct me if I'm wrong. My basic understanding is Frame length should be greater than data length because frame length includes data length.

1) Whether this packet is captured correctly ?

2) In which case this could happen ?

Comment: I agree that sounds wonky. You may want to post packet capture as link to get help with it. It may be a bug with Wireshark.

Comment: Possibly a sign of IP fragmentation and you're looking at the reassembled packet?

Answer (score 0):

I found its related to fragmented packet. This case occurs when packet reassembled.